# C returning numpy array with incorrect values

Tags: python, c, numpy

The extension below is just a small test to output an array of integers from C to python as numpy arrays using the PyArray_SimpleNewFromData() function.

```
#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
#include <Python.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test_func.h"


static PyObject *sum_c(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{

    PyObject *result;
    int a, b;
    int ans[1]={1};
    npy_intp dims[1] = {1};


    //Parse arguments
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "ii", &a, &b)){
        return NULL;
    }

    result = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, &dims[0], NPY_INT, ans);

    return result;
}


static PyMethodDef module_methods[] = {
    {"sum_c", sum_c, METH_VARARGS, "Sum two unsigned integers and returns the answer in numpy dtype"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC init_test_func(void){
    (void) Py_InitModule("_test_func", module_methods);
    import_array();
}
```

Following compiling and importing into python, the result is a 1x1 numpy array not with the value 1 (which in the code is the test value).

My best guess is the interpretation of the C dtype, though NPY_INT should match the INT dtype in C?

Answer (score 0):

Found the mistake, I need to malloc() the return variable, as such:

```
PyObject *result;
    int a, b;
    //int ans[1]={1};
    int *ans;
    npy_intp dims[1] = {1};

    ans = (int *)malloc(1*sizeof(int));
    ans[0] = 4;
```

Comment: This solves one problem, but you're still leaking memory. The buffer you allocated is never cleaned up.